# What is the name of this ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, esters

[image]

Can you tell me the name of this ester? It is two $\ce{C8}$ fatty acids ester-linked with a molecule of 1,3-butanediol in the middle. I would be tempted to say (*R*)-butanediol-1,3-diyl dihexanoate, but I am really not sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* the names of esters are usually formed by placing the alcoholic component in front of the name as a separate word. The particular subsections concerning esters from a single alcoholic component and multiple acid components read as follows:

> **P-65.6.3.3.3** Polyesters formed from a single ‘alcoholic’ component
>
> Esters derived from a single ‘polyhydroxylic’ component are named by placing the name of the ‘polyhydroxylic’ component denoted by a multivalent organyl group (alkyl, aryl, etc.) in front of the name(s) of the acid component denoted by the anion names derived from the appropriate acid(s) (…).
>
> **P-65.6.3.3.3.1** When anions are identical, functional class multiplicative nomenclature is used. Names are formed by citing the multivalent group, the multiplicative prefix, and the multiplied anionic component name. Multiplicative prefixes ‘di’, ‘tri’, etc. are used when anions are unsubstituted; when substituted, prefixes ‘bis’, ‘tris’, etc. are used.

In this case, the polyhydroxylic component is denoted by the multivalent organyl group ‘butane-1,3-diyl’. The acid component is denoted by the anion name ‘hexanoate’, which is derived from the corresponding acid ‘hexanoic acid’. Since both acid components are identical and unsubstituted, the multiplicative prefix ‘di’ is used in functional class multiplicative nomenclature. Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name for the compound given in the question is **(3​*R*)-butane-1,3-diyl dihexanoate**.

[image: (3R)-butane-1,3-diyl dihexanoate]